# Incline Plane problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

If a block is at rest on the incline plane at an angle of 30 degrees, would the maximum frictional force that would allow the block to stay in place be calculated using 30 degrees, OR would we have to find the minimum angle of the incline plane needed for the block to slide before we can determine the maximum frictional force? That is, find that minimum angle using tangent inverse of the coefficient of friction given (between the surfaces) and then substitute it in the formula for fs(max) = UsMgcos (minimum angle needed for block to slide) to get the maximum frictional force that would allow the block to stay in place?

Comment: You asked the same question a few minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way could be as follows: 
1)  firstly draw the free body diagram of the block on the incline and resolve all forces parallel and perpendicular to the incline. Now since there is no motion in the direction perpendicular to the plane so you get normal force by the incline ie $ N = mgcos(30°) $
2)  Now the maximum static friction which the block can encounter will be $ f= \mu mg cos30° $
3)  Now the force responsible for the motion of the block parallel to the incline is $ F =  mgsin30° $
4)  If the maximum friction force is greater than or equal to force F then the block will not not move. 
5)  As we know that static friction is a self adjusting force so if F is less than or equal to f then the magnitude of friction acting on the block will be equal to F. 
6)  If F is greater than f then the block will move with some acceleration along the incline.